# Converting data structure to binary data

Tags: javascript, byte

I have the following object in javascript:

```
var arr = {
  'id': 23, // uint32
  'login': 'some string' // char[16]
};
```

I want to convert this object into binary data (array buffer) and send it to a server. I have come up with something like this:

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(36);
var idView = new Int32Array(buffer, 0, 1);
idView[0] = 23321;
var loginView = new Int16Array(buffer, 4, 16);
loginView = "Random username";
```

So I have 4 bytes (1 int32) in `idView` variable and 32 bytes (16 int16) in `loginView` variable.

I want to send it via ajax as binary data, but when I check server-side bytes arr I'm getting:

`[25 91 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`

which is plain wrong. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That's a perfectly correct output.

Since `Buffer` in Node.js [is basically a Uint8Array](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), you can use `Uint8Array` as a debug view:

```
var debugView = new Uint8Array(buffer);

console.log(debugView); // [25, 91, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

There's a line in your code that does what You might not expect to:

```
loginView = "Random username";
```

It just assigns old plain `String` to `loginView`, and not filling up the buffer with integers.

What you might want to do is this:

```
"Random username".split('').forEach((x, i) => loginView[i] = x.charCodeAt(0));
```

Apparently it is not possible to assign chars to typed arrays either.